# How to show a combobox popover from @reach/combobox inside a MUI dialog component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, combobox, modal-dialog

I'm trying to put a map from google maps API and a combobox popover from `@reach/combobox` inside a MUI dialog component. But I have found a problem, the combobox popover is not being shown. I realized that it is shown if it is not inside the MUI dialog component.

This is the code snippet for the google maps and combobox parts:

```
const libraries = ['places'];
const mapContainerStyle = {
  height: '100%',
  width: '100%',
};
const options = {
  mapId: 'c43de04e5c01e012',
  scaleControl: true,
  scrollwheel: true,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  keyboardShortcuts: false,
  zoomControl: true,
};
const center = {
  lat: 43.653225,
  lng: -79.383186,
};


const MapsLocation = () => {

  const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
    libraries,
  });

  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState({});
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

  const onMapClick = useCallback((e) => {
    setMarkers({
      lat: e.latLng.lat(),
      lng: e.latLng.lng(),
      time: new Date(),
    });
  }, []);

  const mapRef = useRef();
  const onMapLoad = useCallback((map) => {
    mapRef.current = map;
  }, []);

  const panTo = useCallback(({ lat, lng }) => {
    mapRef.current.panTo({ lat, lng });
    mapRef.current.setZoom(14);
  }, []);

  if (loadError) return 'Error';
  if (!isLoaded) return 'Loading ...';

  return (
    <>
      <GoogleMap
        id="map"
        mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
        zoom={9}
        center={center}
        options={options}
        onClick={onMapClick}
        onLoad={onMapLoad}
      >
        <Search panTo={panTo} setMarker={setMarkers} 
        <Locate panTo={panTo} />

        <Marker
          key={uuid()}
          position={{ lat: parseFloat(markers.lat), lng: parseFloat(markers.lng) }}
          onClick={() => {
            setSelected(markers);
          }}
          icon={{
            url: '/static/illustrations/retailer.svg',
            origin: new window.google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new window.google.maps.Point(30, 30),
            scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(55, 55),
          }}
        />

        {selected ? (
          <InfoWindow
            position={{ lat: selected.lat, lng: selected.lng }}
            onCloseClick={() => {
              setSelected(null);
            }}
          >
            <div>
              <h2>
                Alert
              </h2>
              <p>Spotted {formatRelative(selected.time, new Date())}</p>
            </div>
          </InfoWindow>
        ) : null}
      </GoogleMap>
    </>
  );
};

function Locate({ panTo }) {
  return (
    <IconButton
      aria-label="compass"
      onClick={() => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
          panTo({
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
          });
        });
      }}
    >
      <ExploreIcon />
    </IconButton>
  );
}

function Search({ panTo, setMarker }) {
  const {
    ready,
    value,
    suggestions: { status, data },
    setValue,
    clearSuggestions,
  } = usePlacesAutocomplete({
    requestOptions: {
      location: {
        lat: () => 43.6532,
        lng: () => -79.3832,
      },

      radius: 100 * 1000,
    },
  });


  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSelect = async (address) => {
    setValue(address, false);
    clearSuggestions();

    try {
      const results = await getGeocode({ address });
      const { lat, lng } = await getLatLng(results[0]);

      setMarker({ lat, lng, time: new Date() });
      panTo({ lat, lng });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
    }
  };

  console.log('data: ', data,'status: ', status);
  return (
    <div className="search">
      <Combobox onSelect={handleSelect}>
        <ComboboxInput value={value} onChange={handleInput} disabled={!ready} placeholder="Search your location" />
        <ComboboxPopover>
          <ComboboxList>
            {status === 'OK' && data.map(({ id, description }) => <ComboboxOption key={uuid()} value={description} />)}
          </ComboboxList>
        </ComboboxPopover>
      </Combobox>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then, this component is called in the MUI dialogContent component as follow:

```
<DialogContent dividers>
   <MapsLocation />
</DialogContent>
```

Now it looks like this (the poopover is not being shown) [image: dialog1]

I would like to know how I can make the poopover show when it is inside the MUI dialog component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `zIndex` style to `<Combobox/>` component. Like:

```
<Combobox style={{zIndex: 9999999999}}>
...
</Combobox>
```

Comment: I tried something similar, but now I've tried with the number you suggest. It doesn't work stil.

Comment: Try giving `zIndex` to component `<ComboboxPopover>`.
`<ComboboxPopover style={{zIndex: 9999999999}} >...</ComboboxPopover>`